# Making my Multi-threaded Task Asynchronous VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

So I have a task which loops through a sub as many times as there are people in my array. I know that making this Async will be a lot better, but I am not sure the best way to go about doing this. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub status()
    Dim selectedStreamers As New List(Of String)
    For Each item In streamerList.CheckedItems
        selectedStreamers.Add(item)
    Next
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
    For Each streamerName In selectedStreamers
        Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                     streamerOnline(streamerName)
                                     Select Case condition
                                         Case StreamersCondition.Streaming
                                             Me.Invoke(Sub() console.Text &= streamerName + " is online." & vbNewLine)
                                         Case StreamersCondition.Offline
                                             Me.Invoke(Sub() console.Text &= streamerName + " is offline." & vbNewLine)
                                         Case StreamersCondition.UserNotFound
                                             Me.Invoke(Sub() console.Text &= streamerName + " hasn't been found." & vbNewLine)
                                     End Select
                                 End Sub)
        tasks.Add(t)
    Next
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Also, nothing related to the question at hand, but if I wanted to constantly check that the streamers were streaming. I would set up a timer, right? Except I can't seem to get this working whilst running this sub? So is there any good way to keep constantly checking (so running this sub) twice per minute?

Comment: You do know that `Async/Await` already relies on tasks, right? What makes you think switching to it would make your code work better (other than making it easier to read)?

Comment: I didn't realize that was the case, so there is no need make it async as it already is!

Comment: It's been a while since I used it, but there is also a way to do a parallel foreach where you can optionally specify the level of parallelism. I believe using Tasks as you have them now are better, but I would like to see whoever answers this discuss the difference and how Tasks behave if you fire say 1000 of them off all at once.

Comment: @dwilliss, `Parallel.ForEach` uses `Tasks` itself.  I don't know this for a fact but I would expect that `Tasks` use the `ThreadPool` which means that each one gets queued and a maximum number can be executed concurrently.